# x64 function call arguments push/mov order (MSVC)

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, disassembly

I am learning x64 assembly and with a basic sample app with MS VC toolset. [Microsoft documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) that the first 4 args will be pushed in RC, RD, R8, R9 for integer and pointer variables and rest of the variables will use stack. I understand that and it looks like it from the code snippet, assembly debug below but I am unable to understand why these are not done in order? I was expecting the disassembly to appear pushing arguments from right to left order e,d,c,b,a,cp,ip in the below example but what i see being pushed is e, b, a, etc.
Can someone explain it? TIA

Code Snippet

```
__declspec(noinline) int testArgsAsm(int* x, char* cp, int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    std::cout << *x << *cp;
    int sum = a + b + c + d + e;
    if (sum == 0)
        std::cout << "0";
    else
        std::cout << "Non 0";
    return sum;

}
int main(int argc, const char** args)
{
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    int* ip = new int; *ip = 0x101;
    char* cp = new char; *cp = ('g');
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
    testArgsAsm(ip, cp, a,b,c,d,e);
    return 0;
}

Assembly

    testArgsAsm(ip, cp, a,b,c,d,e);
00007FF694DB1359  mov         eax,dword ptr [e]  
00007FF694DB135D  mov         r9d,dword ptr [b]  
00007FF694DB1362  mov         r8d,dword ptr [a]  
00007FF694DB1367  mov         dword ptr [rsp+30h],eax  
00007FF694DB136B  mov         eax,dword ptr [d]  
00007FF694DB136F  mov         dword ptr [rsp+28h],eax  
00007FF694DB1373  mov         eax,dword ptr [c]  
00007FF694DB1377  mov         rdx,rbx  
00007FF694DB137A  mov         rcx,rdi  
00007FF694DB137D  mov         dword ptr [rsp+20h],eax  
00007FF694DB1381  call        testArgsAsm (07FF694DB1270h)  <= Instruction pointer

registers at this instant
    RAX = 0000000000000003 RBX = 0000025633A16030 RCX = 0000025633A13EC0 RDX = 0000025633A16030
RSI = 0000000000000000 RDI = 0000025633A13EC0 R8  = 0000000000000001 R9  = 0000000000000002 
R10 = 000000000000000F R11 = 000000F5016F0001 R12 = 0000000000000000 R13 = 0000000000000000 
R14 = 0000000000000000 R15 = 0000000000000000 RIP = 00007FF694DB1381 RSP = 000000F5016FFB00 
RBP = 0000000000000000 EFL = 00000202
```

PS: it may be a noob question as I am just starting to learn asy

Comment: The arguments in registers are left to right. Any of the remaining parameters that have to go on the stack are right to left.

Comment: Should also point out that there are 32 bytes (0x20 hex) that have to be allocated after the parameters are pushed on the stack per the 64-bit calling convention (shadow space). That means that ultimately `e` is pushed starting at 0x30, `d` at `0x28` and `c` at `0x20` (0x00 to 0x20 is the 32 bytes of shadow space). `x` went in `rcx`, `cp` in `rdx`, `a` in `r8` and `b` in r9`

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelPetch for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am unable to understand why these are not done in order?

All that matters is having the correct values in the correct registers at `call`.  It doesn't matter what order they're put there.

The only reason to go in reverse order with stack args is when you're using `push` to allocate stack space for them at the same time as storing them.  MSVC chooses not to do that, using `mov` instead, so (other than possible performance differences) it makes zero difference which order the args are written in memory, as long as each one is written to the right place.

This caller has already reserved space for args + the 32 byte shadow space (where the register args could be spilled by the callee to form an array of args if it wanted), so it's using `mov` instead of `push`.

---

It's not uncommon for functions to use their first args first, so **setting it up first in the caller might avoid a latency bottleneck and mean out-of-order execution doesn't have to look as far to find instructions that have their inputs ready** when the front-end starts issuing instructions from the called function.  (http://agner.org/optimize/).

Or simply that the compiler parsed the function args from left to right and ended up emitting asm that went in that order.